# Panel Forms passing back and forth

Tags: vb.net

```
MainForm.PanelMenu.Controls.Clear()
MainForm.TopLevel = False 
MainForm.PanelMenu.Controls.Add(MainForm)
MainForm.Show()
```

this bunch of codes should go to module and go back but it have this error

"Additional information: A circular control reference has been made. A control cannot be owned by or parented to itself."

Comment: The error code tells you.  You're trying to add Mainform to a control contained in it.  Try creating a separate instance of the form you're trying to add.

Comment: `MainForm.PanelMenu.Controls.Add(MainForm)` any idea why you are doing this, that's the issue...

Comment: This is a function that adds a form to panel. just having this problem when it comes on working with back buttons

Comment: MainForm.PanelMenu.Controls.Add(MainForm) it seems you are adding form to itself. Probably you have to revisit your design and then create a usercontrol preferably or a child form which you add it to MainForm.

Comment: Can you give me a sample Makul Varshney

Comment: Samle - remove this line: `MainForm.PanelMenu.Controls.Add(MainForm)`